# Access denied on other users mysite after deploying delegate control

Tags: permissions, delegate-control

I created a delegate control and deploy it on all existing my sites. When I go to my own mysite the delegate control is working fine.

When I go to the mysite of someone else I got an access denied. I think it is because of this code below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var permissionsScope = new SPSecurity.GrantAdditionalPermissionsInScope(SPBasePermissions.AddAndCustomizePages))
            {
                // check if the current webTemplate settings exists. If not exists do nothing.
                if (WebTemplateSettingsExists())
                {
                    AddSiteLidMaatschapWebPart();
                }

                // always deactivate the provisioning feature
                DeactivateProvisioningFeature();
            }
        }
```

I am talking about "permissionsScope". My target is to run this code under these permissions. I would like to avoid runwithelevatedprivilidges. Why do I got an access denied?

ps. my account has only read permissions on all other mysites. Only on my own mysite I have full control.

Answer (score 0):

Would not this `DeactivateProvisioningFeature();` (if it does what it says it does) require higher permissions than `AddAndCustomizePages`?

For example, you would need `FullControl` at least to enable or disable site collection scoped features.

Comment: do you mean: SPBasePermissions.FullMask ?

Comment: Yes, in the `SPBasePermissions`enum that would be the equivalent